# How to remove square bracket from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I came up with values in square bracket(more like a `list`) after applying `str.findall()` to column of a pandas dataframe. How can I remove the square bracket ?

```
print df

id     value                 
1      [63]        
2      [65]       
3      [64]        
4      [53]       
5      [13]      
6      [34]
```

Comment: what are the contents of that column, is this a string `'[63]'` or a list `[63]`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If values in column `value` have type `list`, use:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str[0]
```

Or:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str.get(0)
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings).

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[[63],[65],[64]]})
print (df)
  value
0  [63]
1  [65]
2  [64]

#check type if index 0 exist
print (type(df.loc[0, 'value']))
<class 'list'>

#check type generally, index can be `DatetimeIndex`, `FloatIndex`...
print (type(df.loc[df.index[0], 'value']))
<class 'list'>

df['value'] = df['value'].str.get(0)
print (df)
   value
0     63
1     65
2     64
```

If `strings` use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and then convert to numeric by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str.strip('[]').astype(int)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':['[63]','[65]','[64]']})
print (df)
  value
0  [63]
1  [65]
2  [64]

#check type if index 0 exist
print (type(df.loc[0, 'value']))
<class 'str'>

#check type generally, index can be `DatetimeIndex`, `FloatIndex`...
print (type(df.loc[df.index[0], 'value']))
<class 'str'>


df['value'] = df['value'].str.strip('[]').astype(int)
print (df)
  value
0    63
1    65
2    64
```

Comment: `df['value'].dtype` gave `dtype('O')`

Comment: And what `type(df.ix[0, 'value'])` ?

Comment: is it possible to have result as `dtype: float64` ?

Comment: Yes, use `astype`: `df['value'] = df['value'].str.get(0).astype(float)`

Comment: But if the list has multiple string elements ; it returns only the first one. Eg: for me without get(0) it shows outout in csv as ["string1","string2"] but afetr i use it; i get only "string1"; i further donot get the rest of the strings.

Comment: @separ1 - yes exactly. `df['value'].str.get(0)` or `df['value'].str[0]` means give fist value of lists. If need al values, need `df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['value'].values.tolist())`

Comment: @jezrael  if we have two lists to be listed in a df; say one list having single line strings, another havg multiline strings it would make it hard to put both in one df. like

Comment: @separ1 - Can you create question? The best `sample data` (change `df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[[63],[65],[64]]})` as you need), desired output and what you try. Because in commnets it is hard find solution for it. Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael like i want to store everythg in only one df under diff fields
df['value1'] = df['value1'].str.get(0) //value 1 is single line thing
df['value2'] = pd.DataFrame(df['value2'].values.tolist()) something like this would not work. Really sorry to stretch the discussion but have genuine doubt.

Comment: @separ1 - What is df? Can you add sample?

Comment: @jezrael let "resultdf" be the resulting dataframe and i want to store "list1" and "list2" in it; where"list1" = ['one','two','three'] and list2 =['look at my multiline text1','look multiline2','multiline3']
resultdf['col1'] = list1 and resultdf['col2'] = list2
now:resultdf['col1'] = resultdf['col1'].str.get(0) //would work for col1 single single line elements
but resultdf['col2'] = pd.DataFrame(df['value'].values.tolist()) //would not

Comment: Do you think `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[['one','two','three']], 'col2':[['look at my multiline text1','look multiline2','multiline3'] ]})` ? What is desired ooutput?

Comment: Do you need `print (df.apply(lambda x: x.str[0]))` ?

Comment: What to do when I have `[63, 23]` (2 values in the list) instead of [63]?

Comment: What do you mean by 0?

Comment: @xkderhaka it means first value, python count from 0

Comment: so `.str[0]` is saying convert from list to string starting at the 0 value?

Comment: @ElphiusMostafa - it means extract first value from one element lists, `0` is used because python counts from `0`

Answer (score 8):

if string we can also use string.replace method

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame({'value':['[63]','[65]','[64]']})

print(df)
  value
0  [63]
1  [65]
2  [64]

df['value'] =  df['value'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('[','').replace(']','')) 

#convert the string columns to int
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(int)

#output
print(df)

   value
0     63
1     65
2     64

print(df.dtypes)
value    int32
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

A general solution to remove `[` and `]` chars from a dataframe *`string`* column is

```py
df['value'] = df['value'].str.replace(r'[][]', '', regex=True)  # one by one
df['value'] = df['value'].str.replace(r'[][]+', '', regex=True) # by chunks of one or more [ or ] chars
```

The `[][]` is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in regex, that matches a `]` or `[` char. `+` makes the regex engine match these chars one or more times sequentially.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CHRBDR/1).

**However**, in this case, the square brackets mark the *list* of strings that was a result of [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html). It is clear that you wanted to extract *one*, the first match from the column values.

- When you need the first match, use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)
- When you need all matches, use `Series.str.findall`

So, in this case, to avoid this trouble you found yourself in, you could use

```py
df['value'] = df['source_column'].str.extract(r'my regex with one set of (parentheses)')
```

Note that `str.extract` requires at least one set of capturing parentheses to actually work and return a value (`str.findall` works even without a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)).

Note if you were to get multiple matches with `findall`, and you wanted a single string as output, you could `str.join` the matches:

```py
df['value'] = df['source_column'].str.findall(pattern).str.join(', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by jezrael won't work if there are multiple members in one list. In this case, replace method works.

```
df['column_name'] =  df['column_name'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('[','').replace(']',''))
```

If the members in the list are not integers, you have to convert them.

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "values in column values have type list" solution by jezrael won't work if there are multiple members in one list. You can use "lambda" solution by qaiser and sumit. But convert it into "str" before apply the method. Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[[70,63],[12,65],[64,39]]}).astype(str) #list converted into string, so we can use str.replace
df=df['value'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("[","").replace("]",""))
```

output:

```
0    70, 63
1    12, 65
2    64, 39
Name: value, dtype: object
```