# Removing brackets from SQL connection in Python dataframe

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, dataframe

I have a table out of a SQL query in my Python Notebook which gives me the following dataframe:

[image]

My ultimate goal is to group by the second column, which is a boolean, and get the mean per group of the first column (ranges from 1 to 10)

The problem is I haven't been able to remove the brackets efficiently, thus making it impossible to calculate anything from the 1st column. So far I have tried this:

```
val = df.values
val
```

Followed by:

```
list = [i[0] for i in val]
z = map(ast.literal_eval,list)
zz= list(z)
zz
```

which had worked went I wanted to use a value such as: [ 367, 368, 370] from a column (which are choices from a multiple choice question, to give you a bit of context) But in this case it doesn't work. Maybe because of the Boolean next to it ? I really don't know.

EDIT: SQL Query:

```
pd.read_sql
('
SELECT U.iUserSexeType, CA.jAnswer 
FROM [User] U 
JOIN DBO.ConsultationAnswer CA ON CA.fkiUserId=U.id 
LEFT JOIN UserAdresse UA ON UA.fkiUserId=U.id 
WHERE fkiConsultationSurveyId=37 and fkiConsultationQuestionId=260
')
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to remove bracket in your sql query:

```
Select replace(replace(JAnswer,'['),']')
from your table
```

Your query:

```
SELECT U.iUserSexeType, replace(replace(CA.jAnswer,'['),']') as jAnswer
FROM [User] U 
JOIN DBO.ConsultationAnswer CA ON CA.fkiUserId=U.id 
LEFT JOIN UserAdresse UA ON UA.fkiUserId=U.id 
where fkiConsultationSurveyId=37 
and fkiConsultationQuestionId=260
```

Comment: The SQL query is as follows:  pd.read_sql('SELECT U.iUserSexeType, CA.jAnswer FROM [User] U JOIN DBO.ConsultationAnswer CA ON CA.fkiUserId=U.id LEFT JOIN UserAdresse UA ON UA.fkiUserId=U.id where fkiConsultationSurveyId=37 and fkiConsultationQuestionId=260' (I'll edit my post for clarity), so I should just replace the CA.jAnswer ?

Comment: parc260 = pd.read_sql('SELECT U.iUserSexeType, replace(replace(CA.jAnswer,'['),']') as jAnswer FROM [User] U JOIN DBO.ConsultationAnswer CA ON CA.fkiUserId=U.id LEFT JOIN UserAdresse UA ON UA.fkiUserId=U.id where fkiConsultationSurveyId=37 and fkiConsultationQuestionId=260' , connexion)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you have to escape single quotes.

Comment: parc260 = pd.read_sql('SELECT U.iUserSexeType, replace(replace(CA.jAnswer,''[''),'']'') as jAnswer FROM [User] U JOIN DBO.ConsultationAnswer CA ON CA.fkiUserId=U.id LEFT JOIN UserAdresse UA ON UA.fkiUserId=U.id where fkiConsultationSurveyId=37 and fkiConsultationQuestionId=260' , connexion)

Answer (score 0):

```
    df['value'] = df['value'].str[0]
```

Or:

```
    df['value'] = df['value'].str.get(0)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38147471/7853322