# Removing left brackets at beginning and end of column values throughout dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns that have values in this format: [0.0, 0.2[

Yes, those are two left brackets.  I've removed them once by using an iterative loop, .iloc, .rpartition, and .apply; however, I'm hoping there's a one-liner out there that can help me remove all of them from the entire dataframe.

I tried `df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].replace({"[":""}, regex=True)`, but I receive this error:

error: unterminated character set at position 0

I suspect this is because '[' is a special character.

Here's a sample dataframe:

| district_id | pct_black_hisp | pct_free_red |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | [0.2, 0.4[ | [0.0, 0.2[ |
| 2468 | NaN | [0.4, 0,8[ |

district_id is an int, the other columns are objects.

Comment: You should be using `regex=False`. You're just trying to remove a fixed character, not a regular expression pattern.

Comment: Post a running program including a sample dataframe with these strange characters. That makes it easier to demonstrate a solution.

Comment: I just tried regex=False, and it didn't throw an error, but it also did not remove the left brackets.

Comment: Do you want to remove all of the brackets? Is the final goal to split those two floats into separate columns?

Comment: tdelaney: I will try and post a sample dataframe, though I'm very new to this forum and don't precisely know how to do that.

Comment: I just want to remove all the brackets.  I can take it from there.

Comment: Maybe its as simple as `df = pd.DataFrame({"foo":["[0.0, 0.2[", "1.1 3.3"], "bar":["[2, 999[", "7"]})`. Just something that has a sample of all of the expected strings.

Comment: If these are strings, use `df[cols_to_check].str.replace(r'[][]+', '', regex=True)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: tried doing df[cols_to_check] = [your code] and received error: DataFrame object has no attribute 'str'.

Comment: Ok, so you need to get the string out of your objects,and it is not a regex issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew--realized my index was not sequential.  I reset my index, and then your solution worked!

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147447/how-to-remove-square-bracket-from-pandas-dataframe/69398687#69398687).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution in the comments worked for me--thank you Wiktor!

If these are strings, use
`df[cols_to_check].str.replace(r'[][]+', '', regex=True)` –
Wiktor Stribiżew
Sep 30 at 19:44

Answer (score 0):

Did you simply try the following :

```
df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].str.replace("[","")
```