# Select specific values from pandas column and sum them

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have 8 populations in csv file with format column as well:
[pop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG4yw.png)

I am trying this code to extract only AD and DP Values:

```
import io
import os
import pandas as pd


def read_vcf(path1):
    with open(path1, 'r') as f:
            lines = [l for l in f if not l.startswith('##')]
    return pd.read_csv(
        io.StringIO(''.join(lines)),
        dtype={'#CHROM': str, 'POS': int, 'ID': str, 'REF': str, 'ALT': str,
               'QUAL': str, 'FILTER': str, 'INFO': str},
        sep='\t'
    ).rename(columns={'#CHROM': 'CHROM'})


def extract_AD(info):
    AD= int((info.split(':')[1]).split(',')[0])
    return AD

path1 = "C://Users//USER//Desktop//Anas/VCFs_1/test_1.vcf"

file =read_vcf(path1)


pop1 = file[["FORMAT","NEN_001","NEN_003","NEN_200","NEN_300","LAB_004","LAB_300","LAB_400","LAB_500"]]

cols_to_apply = ["NEN_001","NEN_003","NEN_200","NEN_300","LAB_004","LAB_300","LAB_400","LAB_500"]

tst1pop1 = pd.DataFrame(pop1)
AD= tst1pop1[cols_to_apply].applymap(extract_AD)
#AD= pop1["NEN_001"].apply(extract_AD)


def extract_DP(info):
    DP = info.split(':')[2:3]
    return DP

print("AD Values:"+"\n",AD)


DP= tst1pop1[cols_to_apply].applymap(extract_DP)
print("DP Values:\n",DP)


Sum1 = AD.sum(axis=1)
print(Sum1)
SumAD = sum(Sum1)
print(SumAD)
```

But its giving me DP values in list so i am unable to sum them

Output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrVcT.png)

How can i get dp values in integers out of list so i can sum them by rows?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it? : [How to remove square bracket from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147447/how-to-remove-square-bracket-from-pandas-dataframe)

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str[0]
```

Comment: I am trying this:

DP= tst1pop1[cols_to_apply].applymap(extract_DP)
DP1 = DP[["NEN_001","NEN_003","NEN_200","NEN_300","LAB_004","LAB_300","LAB_400","LAB_500"]].str[0]
print("DP Values:\n",DP1)
But its shwoing me error: Dataframe object has no attribute str

Comment: Yeah, the approach probably only works on columns, i.e. a Series.
Quick and dirty: 
    for column in DP:
        DP[column] = DP[column].str[0]

Comment: how can i extract values from multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit all columns of DP, one simple fix is to loop through columns and change values like this:

```
DP= tst1pop1[cols_to_apply].applymap(extract_DP)

for column in DP: 
    DP[column] = DP[column].str[0].astype(int)

print("DP Values:\n",DP)
```

Comment: I am trying:                                                                                      DP= tst1pop1[cols_to_apply].applymap(extract_DP)

for column in DP: 
    DP[column] = DP[column].str[0]
print("DP Values:\n",DP)
Sum2 = DP.sum(axis=1)
print("Total DP Sum:",Sum2)

but its giving me 0 in all sums?

Comment: Maybe you need to convert to int, as shown in my edit?

Comment: when i try to convert them into int , its showing another error: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer