# Changing cell values of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have below data frame

```
import pandas as pd

dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [1,2,4], 'y' : [3,4,10]}).set_axis(['a', 'b', 'c'], axis = 0)
```

Now I want chance values of certain cells by calling those cells by name. I tried below

```
dat1.iloc['b']['y'] = 999
```

However this generates error as below,

```
>>> dat1.iloc['b']['y'] = 999
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1103, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1653, in _getitem_axis
    raise TypeError("Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key")
TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key
```

Could you please help how to change the cell values under above setup?

Note, there are some good discussions on above subject (e.g. [How to remove square bracket from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147447/how-to-remove-square-bracket-from-pandas-dataframe)), however I dont find any discussion where cell is called by **row and column index names** to change it's value

Comment: What error are you getting? Did I quick test, could update a cell value using ```dat1.loc['b']['y'] = 999 ```

Comment: I have updated my post with the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is that you are using `data.iloc` (which is integer based, like indexing a python list)

since you want to access a specific row/column by label, you would use `data.loc`

here is your revised code :

```
import pandas as pd

dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [1,2,4], 'y' : [3,4,10]}).set_axis(['a', 'b', 'c'], axis = 0)

# Using .loc to change the value based on labels
dat1.loc['b', 'y'] = 999

print(dat1)
```

this will print

```
   x    y
a  1    3
b  2  999
c  4   10
```